# spring tx:annotation-driven ignores mode when load time weaving is enabled in tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, transactions, spring-aop

I am trying to configure transactions using annotations.  When I am running in an environment with load time weaving enabled (e.g., tc server or tomcat with the weaving classloader), it seems that my transaction interception is handled by aspectj, but since it is not fully configured it doesn't work (I get a message `"Skipping transactional joinpoint [<method name>] because no transaction manager has been configured"`).

My config states `<tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />`.  Those should all be defaults anyway, but I'm explicitly specifying proxy mode and getting aspectj mode.  If I switch to mode aspectj it works, but our production environment doesn't have LTW enabled and I'd prefer to use mode proxy everywhere.

Any idea what's going on?  I'm on Spring 3.0.5, and am using the `HibernateTransactionManager`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the transactionManager bean in your spring xml.

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>
```